# Let $A \subset S$ be a subset of a regular surface $S$. Prove that if $A$ is itself regular then $A$ is open in $S$.

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am trying sho that for each $p \in A$ exist a open $V \subset R3$ tal que $p \in V \cap S$ and $V \cap S \subset A$. Please, help me.

Here is the definition of a regular surface from Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces by Manfredo do Carmo: A subset S⊂R3 is a regular surface if, for each p∈S, there exists a neighborhood V⊂R3 and a map f:U→V∩S of an open set U⊂R2 onto V∩S⊂R3such that

f is $C^{∞}$.

f is a homeomorphism.

Since f is continuous, this means that f has an inverse 
$f^{-1}:V∩S→U$ which is continuous; that is, $f^{-1}$ is the restriction of a continuous map F:W⊂R3→R2 defined on an open set W containing V∩S.

For each q∈U holds f′(q):R2→R3 is one-to-one.

Comment: What does it mean for $A$ to be regular?

Comment: I've been reading Manfredo Do Carmo's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces and there is defined regular surface in section 2.2, page 52

Comment: So $A$ is also a surface? It could have been a regular curve, for example. I suppose you can take a parametrization $\mathbf x$ of $A$ and a parametrization $\mathbf y$ of $S$ and then $\mathbf y^{-1}\circ \mathbf x$ maps an open set in $\Bbb R^2$ to an open set in $\Bbb R^2$, so the image of $\mathbf x$ is open in $S$.

Comment: Yes, A is a surface.